# Method refers to the missing exception в чем ошибка?

Tags: java, исключения, exception-handler

По какой причине мне выдает следующую ошибку?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
        The method statusValidator(String) from the type Cave refers to the missing type StatusSetterException
        StatusSetterException cannot be resolved to a type

        at Entities.Cave$CaveDoor.setStatus(Cave.java:23)
        at Main.main(Main.java:110)
```

У меня есть вложенный класс CaveDoor.

```
    public class CaveDoor{
        private String name;
        private String status;
        public CaveDoor(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
        //status может принимать только CLOSED или OPENED
        public void setStatus(String status){
            try {
                statusValidator(status);
                this.status = status;
            } 
            catch (StatusSetterException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
    public void statusValidator(String string) throws StatusSetterException{
        if  ( (!string.equals( "OPENED")) || (!string.equals( "CLOSED"))) {
            throw new StatusSetterException("status может принимать только CLOSED или OPENED");
        }        
    }
```

В main я создаю экземпляр этого класса и вызываю метод setStatus.

```
Cave.CaveDoor caveDoor = Cave.new CaveDoor("Дверь пещеры");
caveDoor.setStatus("OPENED");
```

Сама Exception у меня самая обыкновенная:

```
package Exceptions;

public class StatusSetterException extends Exception{
    public StatusSetterException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

По какой причине у меня в импорте указано следующее?? Возможно это и есть ответ на мой вопрос в целом, но я не могу понять.

```
The import Entities.Cave.CaveDoor is never used
```

P.s. не спрашивайте почему у меня статус - строка. Так надо.

Comment: А из первой части когда виден код с описанием эксепшена? Похоже что нет

Comment: Не совсем понял что вы пытаетесь донести.

Comment: *"не спрашивайте почему у меня статус - строка. Так надо."* - спрошу: почему не `enum`? Тогда и создание исключение не будет нужно.

Comment: @Зонтик Спасибо. Так и сделал. Исключение, кстати всё равно имеет место быть, даже если статус - enum.

Comment: @keks если у вас будет перечисление: `enum Status {CLOSED, OPENED}`, то переменная типа `Status` может принимать либо значение CLOSED, либо значение OPENED. И то, и другое вас устроит. Правда есть ещё null, поэтому в `setStatus()` надо проверить, не является ли пришедшая в параметрах переменная null'ом. Но это всё. Т.е не надо будет проверять значение на корректность и ни метод `statusValidator()`, ни StatusSetterException вообще не нужны будут.

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю что именно произошло, но я просто создал новый exception с абсолютно таким же наследованием от Exception и тем же конструктором, и всё заработало.Правда, сама логика, котороую я ожидаю от программы (выводить ошибку в случае неверного задания статуса, и ничего не выводить в противном), не работает вследствие того, что по какой то причине у меня метод setStatus не меняет статус, и тот остается null.

upd: проблема в .equals. знак "!" не отрицал входные значения.